# Wrong preg_match - php

Tags: preg-match

I have a question about regular expressions, I can't understand why the function returns 1 when it should return 0, because the string doesn't match the regular expression.

```
$t = preg_match("/DOC|doc|doc_[IVXCL]{1,6}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\.pdf/", "DOC_TRF4_DEZ_2014.pdf");

echo $t;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns TRUE because it matches `DOC`.
You have to group some part in your regex:

```
preg_match("/(?:DOC|doc|doc)_[IVXCL]{1,6}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}\.pdf/", "DOC_TRF4_DEZ_2014.pdf");
//    here __^           __^
```

But  it isn't very clear what you're trying to match.

Comment: I'm trying to match the names of some files. This:
 /[a-z]{3}_[A-Za-z]{5}_[A-Za-z]{1,7}_[A-Z]{1}_[A-Z0-9]{2,5}.pdf/
should match files that start with 3-letter, then appears an underscore, then a 5-letter word and should end with "pdf", but it's not working too.